# Past perfect usage?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

In the following sentence,

> That task was not added to the TODO document because at that time it **had not yet been added** to the main document.

What I mean here is that back then, during the TODO document outline, one task was missing but was added in the meantime.

1. Is this sentence grammatically correct?
2. Is this past perfect usage correct or given the idea that is being conveyed a more suitable tense would be advisable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it's completely correct.
2. Past perfect is the past in the past.